# SQL distinct on INNER JOIN not on the select

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a Rails app with `ActiveStorage`. I have a model `Attachment` which is shared between all possible "attachable" (Establishment, Event etc).

To avoid multi upload of the same file, might have several blobs with the same checksum.

When I list all the attachments, I would like to avoid duplicates..

So basically, I'm trying to add a distinct on a joined table where column is not listed on the final response.

I was able to list all the checksums (distinct) with the SQL code below but actually I don't care about this field. I need all others (from attachments).

If I change the select from `SELECT DISTINCT active_storage_blobs.checksum` to `SELECT DISTINCT active_storage_blobs.checksum, "attachments".*` duplications are not avoided.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT active_storage_blobs.checksum
FROM ((SELECT "attachments".*
       FROM "attachments"
                INNER JOIN "establishments" ON "attachments"."attachable_id" = "establishments"."id"
                INNER JOIN "establishment_managers"
                           ON "establishments"."id" = "establishment_managers"."establishment_id"
       WHERE "establishment_managers"."manager_id" = 683
         AND "attachments"."attachable_type" = 'Establishment'
       ORDER BY "attachments"."id" ASC)
      UNION
      (SELECT "attachments".*
       FROM "attachments"
                INNER JOIN "events" ON "attachments"."attachable_id" = "events"."id"
                INNER JOIN "establishments" ON "events"."establishment_id" = "establishments"."id"
                INNER JOIN "establishment_managers"
                           ON "establishments"."id" = "establishment_managers"."establishment_id"
       WHERE "establishment_managers"."manager_id" = 683
         AND "attachments"."attachable_type" = 'Event'
       ORDER BY "attachments"."id" ASC)) as attachments
         INNER JOIN "active_storage_attachments" ON "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = 'Attachment' AND
                                                    "active_storage_attachments"."name" = 'file' AND
                                                    "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = "attachments"."id"
         INNER JOIN "active_storage_blobs"
                    ON "active_storage_blobs"."id" = "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id"
ORDER BY active_storage_blobs.checksum ASC
```

I also need to be able to use `count` on this request.

It seems that using `SELECT DISTINCT ON (active_storage_blobs.checksum) "attachments".*` works but not for count.

Comment: `might have several blobs with the same checksum` -> so i think you should `group by checksum` and select the first row in each group or `select distinct on checksum` (if postgresql)

Comment: I've tried it but cannot figure it out. Do you have any syntax to do that? Actually that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I missed the "ON". I'll add the final syntax. Thanks @LamPhan!

Comment: Actually, I still have an issue when trying to COUNT with this request since generated request is

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ON (active_storage_blobs.checksum) "attachments".*)`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, here is the answer:
`SELECT DISTINCT ON (active_storage_blobs.checksum) "attachments".*` via a sub query. Not sure at all about the performances but at least I can list correctly + count correctly as well via `ActiveRecord`.

The whole request below:

```sql
select attachments.* FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (active_storage_blobs.checksum) "attachments".*
FROM ((SELECT "attachments".*
       FROM "attachments"
                INNER JOIN "establishments" ON "attachments"."attachable_id" = "establishments"."id"
                INNER JOIN "establishment_managers"
                           ON "establishments"."id" = "establishment_managers"."establishment_id"
       WHERE "establishment_managers"."manager_id" = 683
         AND "attachments"."attachable_type" = 'Establishment'
       ORDER BY "attachments"."id" ASC)
      UNION
      (SELECT "attachments".*
       FROM "attachments"
                INNER JOIN "events" ON "attachments"."attachable_id" = "events"."id"
                INNER JOIN "establishments" ON "events"."establishment_id" = "establishments"."id"
                INNER JOIN "establishment_managers"
                           ON "establishments"."id" = "establishment_managers"."establishment_id"
       WHERE "establishment_managers"."manager_id" = 683
         AND "attachments"."attachable_type" = 'Event'
       ORDER BY "attachments"."id" ASC)) as attachments
         INNER JOIN "active_storage_attachments" ON "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = 'Attachment' AND
                                                    "active_storage_attachments"."name" = 'file' AND
                                                    "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = "attachments"."id"
         INNER JOIN "active_storage_blobs"
                    ON "active_storage_blobs"."id" = "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id"
ORDER BY active_storage_blobs.checksum ASC) as attachments;
ORDER BY "attachments"."id" ASC
```